# Macro MS Word and Excel Pop Up Message box that have checkbox with it

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm not new in Marco in Word and Excel. i do simple macro by use of recording. but i want to enhance some of my task and put it to as easy it will be.

My problem is Finding and Replacing some Text Characters. i have this sticky note in my screen and manually copy and pasting it to Find and Replace "Ctrl + H".

What I want is to minimize it since i get a lot of report that need to run this certain find and replace task.

But I'm having trouble how to make it Pop Up message box that will have a checkbox on it so i can run all find and replace.

I attached an image file for reference and i want it to make in Excel and Word.
[image: Please Click here for image.]

Comment: You just CANNOT use `MsgBox` for checkboxes, take a look at UserForms! ;)

Comment: in case of excel maybe it will be hard so maybe i just save it .xlsm so i just open it whenever i use the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea of replacing words using VBA. The example code I have supplied takes an array of words you'd like to replace, and replaces them with the second array's words. This lets you find several words and once and replace them all at once as well. You could also take this a step further an do an input box or form to load the arrays.

```
Sub Example1()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("hi", "United States", "Mexico")
rplcList = Array("hello", "USA", "MEX")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: can you check my work i attached some image of my work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a userform with checkboxes, create a userform the same way you add a module -> Project window, right click, add UserForm. Then Click on "Toolbox" icon and select a checkbox, which you can locate in the userform.

[image]

Plus some youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oXcct1mOUw

Edit, lets say you have a button and a checkbox in the userform. This is the code in the userform.

*Name of the button is cmd_Calculator;
Name of the checkbox is chb_new*

```
Private Sub cmd_Calculator_Click()

    If Me.chb_new Then
        MsgBox "Checkbox is selected."
    Else
        MsgBox "Checkbox is not selected."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i recently apply all of your comment can i know how the button works? and can you please see my attached image for some review. http://imgur.com/a/0ODuf and this http://imgur.com/a/U4YXU

Comment: Hi sorry i can't understand should I paste this in Replace button? may i know also the code for Cancel button?

Comment: Yes, paste it in the replace button. Then see how it works and change the procedures.

Comment: Hi it seem there are problem with the code. Whenever i check some if the following like dashes it will automatically applied. what i really want is selecting multi checkbox and replacing it by pressing Replace Button.

Comment: i get error with chb_new i have many checkbox named like Slash_Click Dashes_Click etc.

Comment: Well, my example is simply to show you how to make the message box with the checkbox. If you want to run it, name one button `cmd_Calculator` and one checkbox `chb_new`. But it is probably better to watch the video.